# MySQL - Counting rows in preparation for greatest-n-per-group not working?

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Referring to SO and other [sites](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) have given me examples of how to use MySQL to create a 'greatest-n-per-group' query.

My variant on this would be to have a query that returns the first 3 rows of each category.  As the basis for this I need to sort my data into a usable sequence and that is where my problems start.  Running just the sequence query with row numbering shows that changes in category are mostly ignored.  I should have 35 categories returning rows but only 5 do so.

My query:

```
set @c:=0;
set @a:=0;
SELECT IF(@c = tdg, @a:=@a+1, @a:=1) AS rownum,   (@c:=tdg) ,
julian_day, sequence, complete, year, tdg
FROM tsd WHERE complete = 0 
order by tdg, year, julian_day, sequence
```

Do I have a syntax mistake with this query?

Comment: As I have to guess rather than know, I use the comment box: the problem might be that your IF() assumes that all the rows that have common value in tdg should be sequentially in the table (i.e. no other rows in-between). ORDER is not done before the SELECT is done, but after all the rows have been fetched -> @a gets reset. Also, your reference page says you need the dummy column, so read those pages carefully.

Comment: @Makis - I think you're on the right track - I haven't had time to test out your suggestion thoroughly yet but it does make sense - throw your comment in as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here's my comment as an answer:

The problem might be that your IF() assumes that all the rows that have common value in tdg should be sequentially in the table (i.e. no other rows in-between). ORDER is not done before the SELECT is done, but after all the rows have been fetched -> @a gets reset. Also, your reference page says you need the dummy column, so read those pages carefully.